# Getting "Application Defined or Object Defined" error '1004"

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, runtime-error

So I was trying to copy data from different sheet and paste on current and I am getting this error:

> "Application Defined or Object Defined" error '1004"

Can someone help me with this ?

```
Option Explicit
Sub finddata()

Dim fname As String
Dim FinalRow As Long
Dim i As Integer


Sheets("Report").Range("A10:N200").ClearContents
fname = Sheets("Report").Range("A4").Value
FinalRow = Sheets("Database").Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 3 To FinalRow
    If Sheets("Database").Cells(i, 1) = fname Then
    Sheets("Database").Range(Cells(i, 11), Cells(i, 24)).Copy  ----> Getting "Application Defined or Object Defined" error '1004" on this line
    Sheets("Report").Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference to `Cells` isn't on the same sheet as the call to `Range`.  This is mentioned in the docs for [`Range.Item`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx).  It will will work if `Database` is the active sheet but not otherwise.

Try replacing the error line with

```
With Sheets("Database")
    .Range(.Cells(i, 11), .Cells(i, 24)).Copy 
End With
```

Note the periods before `Cells`.

Comment: Can you troubleshoot and tell me the right solution ?

Comment: When I ran it first time it works perfectly second time it gives an error.

Comment: Hey it worked perfectly thank you very much Sir.